# Awk split pattern error: empty line splits in the middle of a line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, split

I'm trying to split a biggish text file (10Gb+) by a fixed # of empty lines with a one liner suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674746/4317058):

```
awk 'BEGIN {nParMax = 100000; npar = 0 ;nFile =0}
     /^$/{npar++;if(npar==nParMax){nFile++;npar=0;next}}
     {print $0 > "split_"nFile".out"}'  fname
```

It gets the job done 99.99% of the time, meaning splitting the file by `nParMax` number of empty lines.

However, once in a time I'm getting the very last paragraph split in the middle (2-3-5 lines, instead of full say 10-15 lines), in the middle of a line.

I would really appreciate an advice on why this happen (wrong regex pattern?) and how to avoid this happening.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

The misbehaving paragraph:

```
# sent_id = 170247_3
# text = В то же время видеокадры с места событий свидетельствуют о том, что после звука, похожего на выстрел, находившихся на площади людей охватила паника.
1       В       _       ADP     _       _       4       case    _       O
2       то      _       DET     _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing   4       det     _       O
3       же      _       PART    _       _       2       advmod  _       O
4       время   _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing   9       obl     _       O
5       видеокадры      _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Plur   9       nsubj   _       O
6       с       _       ADP     _       _       7       case    _       O
7       места   _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Gen|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing   5       nmod    _       O
8       событий _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Gen|Gender=Neut|Number=Plur   7       nmod    _       O
9       свидетельствуют _       VERB    _       Aspect=Imp|Mood=Ind|Number=Plur|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin|Voice=Act      0       root    _       O
10      о       _       ADP     _       _       11      case    _       O
11      том     _       PRON    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Loc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing   9       obl     _       O
12      ,       _       PUNCT   _       _       25      punct   _       O
13      что     _       SCONJ   _       _       25      mark    _       O
14      после   _       ADP     _       _       15      case    _       O
15      звука   _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Gen|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing   25      obl     _       O
16      ,       _       PUNCT   _       _       17      punct   _       O
17      похожего        _       ADJ     _       Case=Gen|Degree=Pos|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing     15      amod    _       O
18      на      _       ADP     _       _       19      case    _       O
19      выстрел _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing   17      obl     _       O
20      ,       _       PUNCT   _       _       15      punct   _       O
21      находившихся    _       VERB    _       Animacy=Anim|Aspect=Imp|Case=Acc|Number=Plur|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part|Voice=Act 24      acl     _       O
22      на      _       ADP     _       _       23      case    _       O
23      площади _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Loc|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing    21      obl     _       O
24      людей   _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Anim|Case=Acc|Gender=Masc|Number=Plur   25      obj     _       O
25      охватила        _       VERB    _       Aspect=Perf|Gender=Fem|Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Fin|Voice=Act   11      acl     _       O
26      паника  _       NOUN    _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Nom|Gender=Fem|Number=Sing    25      nsubj   _       O
27      .       _       PUNCT   _       _       9       punct   _       O
```

The resulting split:

```
# sent_id = 170247_3
# text = В то же время видеокадры с места событий свидетельствуют о том, что после звука, похожего на выстрел, находившихся на площади людей охватила паника.
1       В       _       ADP     _       _       4       case    _       O
2       то      _       DET     _       Animacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing   4       det     _       O
3
```

The next splitted file starts cleanly, as it supposed to. Half paragraph is lost somewhere.

**Edit 2**

The same para (`# sent_id = 170247_3$`) in VIM with special chars on (`:set list`). The split happens on line 3 (see above):

```
# sent_id = 170247_3$
# text = В то же время видеокадры с места событий свидетельствуют о том, что после звука, похожего на выстрел, находившихся на площади людей охватила паника.$
1^IВ^I_^IADP^I_^I_^I4^Icase^I_^IO$
2^Iто^I_^IDET^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing^I4^Idet^I_^IO$
3^Iже^I_^IPART^I_^I_^I2^Iadvmod^I_^IO$
4^Iвремя^I_^INOUN^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing^I9^Iobl^I_^IO$
5^Iвидеокадры^I_^INOUN^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Plur^I9^Insubj^I_^IO$
6^Iс^I_^IADP^I_^I_^I7^Icase^I_^IO$
7^Iместа^I_^INOUN^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Gen|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing^I5^Inmod^I_^IO$
8^Iсобытий^I_^INOUN^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Gen|Gender=Neut|Number=Plur^I7^Inmod^I_^IO$
9^Iсвидетельствуют^I_^IVERB^I_^IAspect=Imp|Mood=Ind|Number=Plur|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin|Voice=Act^I0^Iroot^I_^IO$
10^Iо^I_^IADP^I_^I_^I11^Icase^I_^IO$
11^Iтом^I_^IPRON^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Loc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing^I9^Iobl^I_^IO$
12^I,^I_^IPUNCT^I_^I_^I25^Ipunct^I_^IO$
13^Iчто^I_^ISCONJ^I_^I_^I25^Imark^I_^IO$
14^Iпосле^I_^IADP^I_^I_^I15^Icase^I_^IO$
15^Iзвука^I_^INOUN^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Gen|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing^I25^Iobl^I_^IO$
16^I,^I_^IPUNCT^I_^I_^I17^Ipunct^I_^IO$
17^Iпохожего^I_^IADJ^I_^ICase=Gen|Degree=Pos|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing^I15^Iamod^I_^IO$
18^Iна^I_^IADP^I_^I_^I19^Icase^I_^IO$
19^Iвыстрел^I_^INOUN^I_^IAnimacy=Inan|Case=Acc|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing^I17^Iobl^I_^IO$
20^I,^I_^IPUNCT^I_^I_^I15^Ipunct^I_^IO$
21^Iнаходившихся^I_^IVERB^I_^IAnimacy=Anim|Aspect=Imp|Case=Acc|Number=Plur|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part|Voice=Act^I24^Iacl^I_^IO$
22^Iна^I_^IADP^I_^I_^I23^Icase^I_^IO$
```

Comment: could you please post sample of that paragraph which is causing issues in your question and let us know then(not my down vote btw).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Edited per your request

Comment: As there are some down votes, I would really appreciate if people downvoting shared why they are doing that. Maybe I'm missing something trivial?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on a file with two pars (the one you've given pasted twice, with an empty row in between). Since you are using non-latin alphabeth, maybe encoding is an issue? Anyway, that pattern is really similar to the one I used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62998356/2125110): you'll always print the line, unless `/^$/`, in which case you might even not print. I would have a look at that statement and debug it.

Comment: @DaemonPainter I have no issue with small test files. It works as it should. However on a real task I have this annoying artefacts.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov for us to be able to help you debug your problem you'll have to be able to create and post a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce your problem. If you dont know where to start, do the usual brute force debugging steps to isolate the problem data - save half your data in file1 and the other half in file2. Run your tool on both. Whichever one reproduces the problem, split that file in half and save the halves in file3 and file4. Run your tool on both... Repeat until you have the smallest possible file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, make sense

Comment: The code in your question is splitting a file into a separate file every nParmax (100000) paragraphs, not splitting the file by nParMax number of empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do or not but to split a file of X paragraphs into n (`10` below) files where X is some number greater than or equal to n as I think you're trying to do would be:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -n 10 '
    NR==FNR { totParas=NR; parasPerFile=2; next }
    (FNR % parasPerFile) == 1 {
        close(out)
        out = FILENAME "_out" (++c)
        parasLeft = totParas - (FNR - 1)
        parasPerFile = int(parasLeft/n) + (parasLeft%n ? 1 : 0)
    }
    { print > out }
' file file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! Concerning your above comment # of paras == # of empty lines, so it does not matter which one to count. I'll try to divide the file until I zero in on the culprit as you suggested.

Comment: Could you please have a look at Edit 2 in the question, with special characters turned on? As a wild guess, as I'm executing the script on server over SSH, could it be due to a file writing closed prematurely?

Comment: I don;t see any `Edit 2` in the question and idk what you mean by "special characters". I guess anythings possible but usually issues like this are just plain old bugs.

Comment: Sorry, may bad. Added now.

Comment: Is the text under `Edit 2` text that if I ran the script in  your question on it it's demonstrate the problem you're having? If not, it's not useful towards debugging your issue. Those "special characters" (`^I`) in it are just tabs - nothing interesting about them. Did you try [what I suggested yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012928/awk-split-pattern-error-empty-line-splits-in-the-middle-of-a-line/63016453?noredirect=1#comment111435978_63012928) to isolate a problem paragraph?

Comment: The text in Edit 2 is where the split happens, with special characters on. Yes, you're right, the split happens on tab, whereas it;s supposed to happen on empty line. One thing I can add is that this bug (?) only happens if I split original 10GB+ file in 100'000 chunks. If I try to split say 300'000 paras file into 100'000, everything goes as it's expected.

Comment: Concerning your suggestion to isolate the problem, I only can add that if I try to do the split on smaller sized files the problem disappears.

Comment: Unfortunately that sounds like you are running into an issue outside of the awk script and outside of your data. Timeout? Memory Exceeded? Something else? You'd have to open a new question with a complete (but minimal) script tagged with the tools you use in that script (ssh and others?) for anyone to be able to help you debug that.